# Troubleshooting a connection to a new LAMP setup

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, lamp

So, I just set up my first LAMP server. I think.

I [followed this guide](http://imperialwicket.com/aws-building-a-lamp-instance)  and then proceeded to connect to it using Filezilla, so that means that it exists, at least.

I made an index.html and placed it inside /var/www/html

However, when I enter in my Elastic IP address or the public DNS and try to navigate to it, my browser tells me that it can't connect.

How can I find out where I went wrong, and fix it?

I saw that I should provide this information from my concurrent Googling:

```
 sudo iptables --list -n -t nat                   
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

There ports are open on the Security Groups tab:

```
20 - 21     0.0.0.0/0   
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   
1024 - 1048 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely don't have port 80 open in your instance's security groups. Check this link for more details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

One other thing you can verify is if apache listening on port 80? Check you Apache configuration or run "netstat -anp | grep 80" as root. Also, make sure your Apache virtual host has your Elastic DNS name (or whatever DNS address you're using to access the server) either as the ServerName or a ServerAlias.

Comment: I replaced `NameVirtualHost *:80` with `NameVirtualHost [the-ip]:80` and that didn't work. I also ran `netstat -anp` and that didn't seem to help. Do I need to restart apache for the changes to take effect?

Comment: Also, I updated my question to include information about my security groups

Comment: Yes, I restarted apache (it told me httpd was not running, and that it would start it), then it worked